# Issues combining ExPeX with Tabular

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, expex

I need to make tables of interlinear gloss. I have successfully made that happen, but the result is ugly. I have two issues in particular:

1. The baselines of the three cells don't line up.
2. The table doesn't align with the left edge of the page.

**MWE:**

```
%XeLaTeX
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[
    paperwidth=8in,
    paperheight=10in,
    inner=0.5in,
    outer=0.5in,
    bindingoffset=0.25in,
    top=0.75in,
    bottom=0.75in,
    twoside,
    showframe
    ]{geometry}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage} 
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow,graphicx,adjustbox,makecell} 

\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{english}
    \setotherlanguage{hebrew}
    \newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Linux Libertine O}
    \newfontfamily\englishfont[Ligatures=NoCommon]{Linux Libertine O}
            
\usepackage{expex}

\makeatletter
\define@lingincdimenkeys{numoffset,textoffset,numvoffset}

\lingset{
    everygla=\LARGE, 
    everyglb=\footnotesize\englishfont,
    everyglc=\footnotesize\englishfont,
    everyglft=\footnotesize\englishfont,
    glwordalign=center,
    glhangindent=0em,
    glrightskip=0pt,
    glhangstyle=none,
    numvoffset=.3ex,   
    aboveglbskip=-0.7ex,
    aboveglcskip=-0.7ex
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{.1\textwidth}|p{.2\textwidth}|p{.6\textwidth}|}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\begin{LARGE}\texthebrew{א־ב־ד}\end{LARGE}} \\
\hline
\parbox[t]{.1\textwidth}{
\smallskip Adjective%
} 
&
\parbox[t]{.2\textwidth}{
\begin{hebrew}\begingl
\gla אבוד //
\glb avud //
\glc lost //
\endgl\end{hebrew}%
} 
&
\parbox[t]{.6\textwidth}{
\begin{hebrew}\begingl
\gla הקורס הזה קשה, אני אבודה לגמרי. //
\glb hakurs haze kasha ani avuda legamre //
\glc \textenglish{the course} \textenglish{the this} difficult I lost completely //
\glft \textenglish{This course is difficult, I am completely lost.} //
\endgl\end{hebrew}%
} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why do you have nested parboxes (a `p` column is a parbox already) it is not necessarily wrong but it complicates getting the alignment

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have removed \parbox, but the result is the same.

Comment: Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

(1) A `\noindent` at the beginning takes care of the left unwanted space.

(2) The misalignment of the hebrew lines is cause by the ascender of the Lamed. Using `\parbox[b]`  and  the same settings for all three cells keeps all baselines aligned.

(3) No need to use p columns. Use   `\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}`

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex 

\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[
paperwidth=8in,
paperheight=10in,
inner=0.5in,
outer=0.5in,
bindingoffset=0.25in,
top=0.75in,
bottom=0.75in,
twoside,
showframe
]{geometry}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage} 
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow,graphicx,adjustbox,makecell} 

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Ligatures=NoCommon]{Linux Libertine O}
    
\usepackage{expex}

\makeatletter
\define@lingincdimenkeys{numoffset,textoffset,numvoffset}
\makeatother

\lingset{
    everygla=\LARGE, 
    everyglb=\footnotesize\englishfont,
    everyglc=\footnotesize\englishfont,
    everyglft=\footnotesize\englishfont,
    glwordalign=center,
    glhangindent=0em,
    glrightskip=0pt,
    glhangstyle=none,
    numvoffset=.3ex,   
    aboveglbskip=-0.7ex,
    aboveglcskip=-0.7ex
}

\begin{document}
    
\noindent   \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|} % changed<<<<<<<
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\begin{LARGE}\texthebrew{א־ב־ד} \end{LARGE}} \\
    \hline
    \parbox[b]{.1\textwidth}{% % changed <<<<<<<   parbox bottom aligned
        \begin{english}
            \begingl[everygla=\normalsize] 
            \gla Adjective //
            \endgl
        \end{english}%
    }
    &
    \parbox[b]{.2\textwidth}{% changed <<<<<<<   parbox bottom aligned
        \begin{hebrew}
            \begingl
            \gla אבוד //
            \glb avud //
            \glc lost //
            \endgl
        \end{hebrew}%
    } 
    &
    \parbox[b]{.6\textwidth}{% changed <<<<<<<   parbox bottom aligned
        \begin{hebrew}
            \begingl
            \gla  הקורס הזה קשה, אני אבודה לגמרי. //
            \glb hakurs haze kasha ani avuda legamre //
            \glc \textenglish{the course} \textenglish{the this} difficult I lost completely //
            \glft \textenglish{This course is difficult, I am completely lost.} //
            \endgl
        \end{hebrew}%
    } 
    \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

[image: z]

Comment: When I fix the right-to-left issue (`\begin{hebrew}`...`\end{hebrew}`) the problem comes back, so I guess it's related to that. However, I still don't know how to fix that.

Comment: @AML I know. I am trying to understand the issue

Comment: @AML I updated the answer

Comment: Looking good, thank you. Is there a way to use `\parbox[b]` within the `\tabular` command to avoid having to set the box sizes twice?

Comment: @AML Of course. Only once is enough. Use `\noindent \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}`. I updated the answer.